# “Expected method body” error

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I had my application working fine, then without doing anything, out of nowhere I got 2 errors in `appDelegate.h`.  One says this:

> Expected selector for Objective-C method

The other says this:

> Expected method body

I have no idea why this is happening, I have other projects with the exact same app delegate and they all work just fine.

This is my appDelegate.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate> // I get the errors here

@property (strong, nonatomic) UITabBarController *tbc; 
@property(strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;

@end
```

Answer (score 23):

I had the same problem. At last I found that in my main.m I had accidentally added a "-" character in the beginning of the file.

Removing the character solved the problem.

Comment: No extra characters should be added to main.m file

Comment: Had same issue, just for protocol. There was a "-" by accident typed in one of the ViewController files. That was so annoying as issue is being point totally different direction.

Comment: Thanks, had the exact same problem in one of my ViewControllers. What a creepy error! Having a look at the build logs helped.

Comment: Thanks a ton! I found it a lot quicker by checking my changed files in my local git repo.

Answer (score 13):

I usually find that a mysterious error like this happens because I accidentally typed a stray character into one of my other source files - either at the end of one of the other header files, or at the top of a `.m` file.

Look at the top of the `.m` file that Xcode is trying to compile.  Check it for stray characters.  If you don't find any, look at which file is imported just before `AppDelegate.h`.  Check for stray characters at the end of that other header file.  If you have header files that import `AppDelegate.h`, you may have to check those too.  (There's really no reason any other `.h` file should have to import `AppDelegate.h`.)

Comment: Had a + at the top of the file, before the comment starts! Was hard to find and had to go back with cmd+z, but i finally found it!

Answer (score 3):

Try closing Xcode and then reopening and doing a clean build.

If that doesn't fix it, it's possible you've got a circular reference in one of your header files.

This can happen when foo.h #imports "bar.h" and bar.h #imports "foo.h" (or sometimes its a chain of three or more header files importing each other in a circle) and it leads to spurious errors like the one you're seeing.

The solution is to try to avoid importing headers in your .h files, and instead use @class references for external classes in the .h files and put the #imports in the .m files instead.

Comment: I've checked for circular reference and its not the case. I have also closed and reopened Xcode, and even restarted my machine and still no success. I didn't try the "Clean Build" though, how do I do that?
Thanks!!

Comment: Just did the clean build and still no luck. Thanks though!! I appreciate your time.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem it was like:

```
-(void) gotoHome(){ ...}
```

Because I am new to objective C, I forgot to "not using" opening and closing braces when send function arguments

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error because I was using RCT_EXPORT_METHOD instead of RCT_EXTERN_METHOD

Comment: Thank you for this comment. Did exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, variable name was reserved to C++ because i change my files to *.mm

Answer (score 0):

Basically the

> Expected method body

is because there is a type/extra character somewhere!

For me it was because the name of Apple's pre-defined's method was mis-spelled.

Answer (score 0):

This message can also happen after pasting some code from Internet. There may be some invisible characters in your snippet.

- What you see in XCode with invisible chars OFF
  [image: What you see in XCode]
- What's hidden (viewed in another text editor)
  [image: What's hidden (viewed in another text editor)]
- What XCode 7.3 shows with invisible chars turned ON*
  [image: What XCode 7.3 shows with invisible chars turned ON]

  *You can configure XCode 7.3 to show the invisible characters by going in "Preferences...>Key bindings". Find "invisible" and choose a key combination (Command+shift+F1 for instance).*

So ONE of the solutions (see others above...) if you have the "Expected Method Body" error is to re-type the erroneous line from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I copied over my new methods in my implementation file over to the header file. I also copied over the @implementation Class(category) line and forgot to change it to @interface.

Answer (score 0):

This message could come up with some invisible characters. Paste your code in another text editor such as `TextMate` you will see it.

[image]