# Multiple Xcode projects will no longer successfully compile on a real iOS device

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, ios-simulator

I might have accidentally edited the NSAttributedString.h class and/or a related class, and it now seems all my Xcode projects including projects I create will not compile on my iPhone (iPhone 4s iOS version: 9.3.2) (my deployment target is iOS 9.0.).

The Xcode projects will successfully build and deploy to a simulated iPhone.

Here is an edited list of errors I get when I try and compile the app for an iPhone:

```
System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSAttributedString.h:13:2: Prefix attribute must be followed by an interface or protocol
System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSAttributedString.h:16:1: Expected method body
System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSAttributedString.h:23:1: Expected method body
System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSAttributedString.h:26:1: Expected method body
System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSAttributedString.h:30:1: Expected method body
System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSAttributedString.h:32:1: Expected method body
System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSAttributedString.h:40:1: Expected method body
System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSAttributedString.h:42:1: '@end' must appear in an Objective-C context
AppPods/Target Support Files/Pods-App/Pods-App-dummy.m:1:9: Could not build module 'Foundation'
Semantic Issue Group
System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSAttributedString.h:14:1: Missing context for method declaration
System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSAttributedString.h:22:1: Missing context for method declaration
System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSAttributedString.h:25:1: Missing context for method declaration
System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSAttributedString.h:28:1: Missing context for method declaration
System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSAttributedString.h:31:1: Missing context for method declaration
System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSAttributedString.h:39:1: Missing context for method declaration
System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSAttributedString.h:45:40: Attempting to use the forward class 'NSAttributedString' as superclass of 'NSMutableAttributedString'
```

I am using Xcode 8 beta.

Does anyone know what would be causing this error?

I've tried restarting and reconnecting the iPhone,restarting Xcode, re-staring my mac, and deleting the DerivedData folder. I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8996811/expected-method-body-error) that the `Expected method body` can be caused by a "stray character" in the code but I couldn't find a stray character.

**Here is the NSAttributedString.h class:**

```
/*  NSAttributedString.h
    Copyright (c) 1994-2015, Apple Inc. All rights reserved.
*/


#import <Foundation/NSString.h>
#import <Foundation/NSDictionary.h> 

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN 

NS_CLASS_AVAILABLE(10_0, 3_2)

@property (readonly, copy) NSString *string;
- (NSDictionary<NSString *, id> *)attributesAtIndex:(NSUInteger)location effectiveRange:(nullable NSRangePointer)range;

@end

@interface NSAttributedString (NSExtendedAttributedString)


@property (readonly) NSUInteger length;
- (nullable id)attribute:(NSString *)attrName atIndex:(NSUInteger)location effectiveRange:(nullable NSRangePointer)range;
- (NSAttributedString *)attributedSubstringFromRange:(NSRange)range;

- (NSDictionary<NSString *, id> *)attributesAtIndex:(NSUInteger)location longestEffectiveRange:(nullable NSRangePointer)range inRange:(NSRange)rangeLimit;
- (nullable id)attribute:(NSString *)attrName atIndex:(NSUInteger)location longestEffectiveRange:(nullable NSRangePointer)range inRange:(NSRange)rangeLimit;

- (BOOL)isEqualToAttributedString:(NSAttributedString *)other;

- (instancetype)initWithString:(NSString *)str;
- (instancetype)initWithString:(NSString *)str attributes:(nullable NSDictionary<NSString *, id> *)attrs;
- (instancetype)initWithAttributedString:(NSAttributedString *)attrStr;

typedef NS_OPTIONS(NSUInteger, NSAttributedStringEnumerationOptions) {
  NSAttributedStringEnumerationReverse = (1UL << 1),
  NSAttributedStringEnumerationLongestEffectiveRangeNotRequired = (1UL << 20)
};

- (void)enumerateAttributesInRange:(NSRange)enumerationRange options:(NSAttributedStringEnumerationOptions)opts usingBlock:(void (NS_NOESCAPE ^)(NSDictionary<NSString *, id> *attrs, NSRange range, BOOL *stop))block NS_AVAILABLE(10_6, 4_0);
- (void)enumerateAttribute:(NSString *)attrName inRange:(NSRange)enumerationRange options:(NSAttributedStringEnumerationOptions)opts usingBlock:(void (NS_NOESCAPE ^)(id _Nullable value, NSRange range, BOOL *stop))block NS_AVAILABLE(10_6, 4_0);

@end

NS_CLASS_AVAILABLE(10_0, 3_2)
@interface NSMutableAttributedString : NSAttributedString

- (void)replaceCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range withString:(NSString *)str;
- (void)setAttributes:(nullable NSDictionary<NSString *, id> *)attrs range:(NSRange)range;

@end

@interface NSMutableAttributedString (NSExtendedMutableAttributedString)

@property (readonly, retain) NSMutableString *mutableString;

- (void)addAttribute:(NSString *)name value:(id)value range:(NSRange)range;
- (void)addAttributes:(NSDictionary<NSString *, id> *)attrs range:(NSRange)range;
- (void)removeAttribute:(NSString *)name range:(NSRange)range;

- (void)replaceCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range withAttributedString:(NSAttributedString *)attrString;
- (void)insertAttributedString:(NSAttributedString *)attrString atIndex:(NSUInteger)loc;
- (void)appendAttributedString:(NSAttributedString *)attrString;
- (void)deleteCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range;
- (void)setAttributedString:(NSAttributedString *)attrString;

- (void)beginEditing;
- (void)endEditing;

@end

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You deleted the `@interface NSAttributedString : NSObject <NSCopying, NSMutableCopying, NSSecureCoding>` below the `NS_CLASS_AVAILABLE(10_0, 3_2)`

Comment: Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 0):

I think you had modified NSAttributedString.m  with mistake.

You can to reinstall the xcode to resolove.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Reinstalling Xcode might have solved the issue but adding the line `@interface NSAttributedString : NSObject <NSCopying, NSMutableCopying, NSSecureCoding>` to the NSAttributedString.h class seems to have solved the issue